# Pass iterator as a function parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, iterator

I try to write a function, which will sum the elements of a container. This container can be Vector, List, Queue, etc... That's why I tried templates.

Unfortunately I get this error:

> 'C' is not a template

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class C, typename T>
T sum( C<T>::iterator begin, C<T>::iterator end ) {
    T s = null;

    for (C<T>::iterator it = begin; it != end; it++) {
        s += *it;
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {5, 9, 0, 11};

    cout << sum(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What do I wrong? How should I fix it?

Comment: In case you want to leverage the benefits of C++ STL, you can use [accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The particular error you get is because you'd need a template template argument:

```
template<template <typename> class C, typename T>
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
T sum( C<T>::iterator begin, C<T>::iterator end )
```

However, the standard containers typically have more than just one template argument:

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector
```

and it is a bit non-trivial to write such function correctly. You could use variadic template arguments, or you could do like the standard library does, and only specialize as much as you really need:

```
// <algorithm>
namespace std {
    template <class RandomAccessIterator>
    void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
}
```

In your case (pretending that your need is not covered by the standard algorithms library already):

```
template <typename Iterator>
auto sum(Iterator begin, Iterator end) 
-> decltype(*begin+*begin) // the type of summing two of them
{
    if (begin == end) throw std::logic_error("....");
    auto s = *begin;
    ++begin;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        s += *begin;
    }
    return s;
}
```

---

There are some more differences from your original code:

- the new code does not assume a null or a default constructor defined (`T s = null;`)
- does not introduce additional iterator (`it`)
- uses pre-increment
- throws an exception when begin==end

---

If you add an `init` parameter, you can make it almost `noexcept`:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename T>
T sum(Iterator begin, Iterator end, T init)
{
    for (; begin!=end; ++begin)
        init += *begin;
    return init;
}
```

But only almost, because `init += *begin` could still throw.

If you have such signature, you've by the way reproduced the signature of `std::accumulate`.

Comment: Is it possible to pass iterator pointers like that?, ie. template <typename Iterator, typename T>
T sum(Iterator *begin, Iterator *end, T init) { .... } ?

Answer (score 24):

You could express the whole thing in terms of a iterator type, and use `iterator_traits` to get the value_type:

```
#include <iterator>

template<typename Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type 
sum(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
  value_type s = value_type();
  for (Iterator it = begin; it != end; it++) {
    s += *it;
  }
  return s;
}
```

In real life, use [std::accumulate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/):

```
int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Comment: +1. but surely `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type s;` ?